# Can't start a self managed node group through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy a self managed node group through terraform, for days now. Deploying a non self managed one works out of the bat, however, I have the following issue with the self managed one. This is what my code looks like:

```
self_managed_node_groups = {
    self_mg_4 = {
      node_group_name        = "self-managed-ondemand"
      subnet_ids             = module.aws_vpc.private_subnets
      create_launch_template = true
      launch_template_os     = "amazonlinux2eks"
      custom_ami_id          = "xxx"
      public_ip              = false
      pre_userdata           = <<-EOT
            yum install -y amazon-ssm-agent \
            systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent && systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent \
        EOT

      disk_size     = 5
      instance_type = "t2.small"
      desired_size  = 1
      max_size      = 5
      min_size      = 1
      capacity_type = ""

      k8s_labels = {
        Environment = "dev-test"
        Zone        = ""
        WorkerType  = "SELF_MANAGED_ON_DEMAND"
      }

      additional_tags = {
        ExtraTag    = "t2x-on-demand"
        Name        = "t2x-on-demand"
        subnet_type = "private"
      }
      create_worker_security_group = false
    }
  }
```

This is the module I use: `github.com/aws-samples/aws-eks-accelerator-for-terraform`

And this is what Terraform throws after 10 mins:

**Error: "Cluster": Waiting up to 10m0s: Need at least 1 healthy instances in ASG, have 0.

Cause: "At 2022-02-10T16:46:14Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1.", Description: "Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations. Launching EC2 instance failed.", StatusCode: "Failed"**

**Full code:**
https://pastebin.com/mtVGC8PP

Comment: please provide the full tf code, module version, tf version.

Comment: Will do, updating code right now

Comment: It might be that the user data for Amazon Linux 2 is not supported for 1.19.

Comment: `custom_ami_id = "xxx"` - your own AMI or...?

Comment: I don't think 5GB is enough. Can you please try with 10 instead? and you should add public / private cluster endpoint in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was actually changing my t2.small to t3.small. Turns out my AZS didn't support t2.